# Scraping a web link with Rvest

Tags: r, coercion, rvest

I am trying to figure out a way to extract a link from a wiki page. 
The web page is the following:

```
wiki <- html("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:1879_births")
```

I am interested by the following link:

```
v =  html_node(wiki, "a[href*='pages']")
<a href="/w/index.php?title=Category:1879_births&amp;pagefrom=Barrymore%2C+Ethel%0AEthel+Barrymore#mw-pages" title="Category:1879 births">next page</a>
```

I want to extract the link after `href` but when I try to convert `v` as a character and split it, I get the following error message: *" cannot coerce type 'externalptr' to vector of type 'character' "*

Does anyone know how to deal with this *"externalptr"* type and extracting the link ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: The data is being stored at the C level.  To extract it you can place `@href` before the brackets.  Maybe try the xpath `//a/@href[contains(., 'pages')]` or since it ends with `pages` maybe `//a/@href['pages'=substring(., string-length(.) - 4)]`

Comment: @RichardScriven It's absolutely perfect. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

This should extract the href attribute:

```
html_attr(v, "href")
```